# How doing for one data in mysql...?

Tags: mysql

i want to have one number account like that NCCA10000000 on begin start and after each auto-incrémentation, each time opening +1 (like NCCA10000001, NCCA10000002, and more, more ), how doing this with mysql...
Having tart's possibility ?

Thank you for your help...?

Christophe.

Comment: I have found solutions...thanks...@+++

Answer (score 0):

You might need a generated column (if you are on 5.7.6 or above) see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

for example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T(ID INT auto_increment primary key, amt int,calccol varchar(10) as (concat('nca1000',id)))

insert into t (amt) values (10);

select * from t;
```

Result

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+------+----------+
| ID | amt  | calccol  |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 |   10 | nca10001 |
+----+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$
Create Procedure CreateAccountNo() 
Begin
Set @AccountName='NCCA';
SET @AccountNo=9999999;
Set @Count=1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AccountListTemp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AccountListTemp (
    AccountName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

while(@Count<10) do
 Set @AccountNo=@AccountNo+1;
 insert into AccountListTemp (AccountName)
    select Concat(@AccountName,cast(@AccountNo as  CHAR(50))) as AccountListTemp;
set @Count=@Count+1;
end while;

 select * from AccountListTemp;

END$$

DELIMITER ; 



call CreateAccountNo()
```

[image]